# Quicksort with Linq performance Advantage passing T[] vs. IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Just for fun I built a quicksort implementation in C# with Linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> quicksort<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) where T : IComparable<T>{
    if (input.Count() <= 1) return input;
    var pivot = input.FirstOrDefault();
    var lesser = quicksort(input.Skip(1).Where(i => i.CompareTo(pivot) <= 0));
    var greater = quicksort(input.Where(i => i.CompareTo(pivot) > 0));
    return lesser.Append(pivot).Concat(greater);
}
```

It sorts 10000 random integers in about 13 seconds.

Changing it to use int[] instead of List results in about 700 times better performance! It only takes 21ms to sort the same 10000 random integers.

```
public static T[] quicksortArray<T>(T[] input) where T : IComparable<T>{
    if (input.Count() <= 1) return input;
    var pivot = input.FirstOrDefault();
    var lesser = quicksortArray(input.Skip(1).Where(i => i.CompareTo(pivot) <= 0).ToArray());
    var greater = quicksortArray(input.Where(i => i.CompareTo(pivot) > 0).ToArray());
    return lesser.Append(pivot).Concat(greater).ToArray();
}
```

Just looking at the code I would have assumed this would have worse
performance. I assumed that .ToArray() would create an additional array in memory and copy all integers there.
I think passing an array vs. passing a list should take about the same time.

So where does this huge performance difference come from?

Comment: https://ideone.com/E5ASv7, https://ideone.com/DAUfmB

Comment: you might be a bit surprised after comparing `quicksortArray` to `Array.Sort` too

Comment: @Slai I know this is not efficient and would not use it for anything :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why you should be *very* careful about iterating an `IEnumerable` multiple times.

The first time you call `quicksort` you pass in, say,  `List`.  It calls `quicksort` two more times, in each of those cases, the `IEnumerable` that you're passing in represents a query that will skip the first item and then perform a comparison on every single item after that.  You then take that query and pass it to two *more* instances of `quicksort`, but making the query not only skip the first item and compare every item after it, but then skip the first item of the results of that query and then compare every item after *that* to something.  This means that by the time you finally reach a value, you've got a query that represents log(n) skips, and is comparing every item in the sequence to a value log(n) times.

In your second implementation  you're not passing in *queries* to `quicksort`, you're evaluating those queries to their values and passing in *the values* to the operation, which can then use those values twice, rather than continually performing an extremely complex query multiple times.

Comment: That's a whole lot of skips.

Comment: Thanks, adding an explicit .toList() to the first example fixes this performance difference. I was under the (wrong) assumption that .toList() would be implicitly done the first time the query result was used.

Comment: @marv51 It's of course worth noting that your concerns with constantly copying the data are merited.  Basically your solution is going to be something like O(n^2*log(n)), as opposed to a good solution that would be O(n*log(n)), it's just that the code from your first sample is O((2^n)*log(n)) which is just *insanely* bad, making the still-bad version with the copy look amazing in comparison.  You shouldn't *actually* use either.

Answer (score 4):

The thing about linq queries are they are lazy, they won't be evaluated until you call a method like `ToArray` or `ToList`. In your first code for example, this query:

```
input.Skip(1).Where(i => i.CompareTo(pivot))
```

Will be evaluated at least twice every time you call `quicksort`, once for `Count()` and once for `FirstOrDefault`. Which means the filtering operation will be repeated for each call over and over. When you use `ToArray` on the other hand, since you have the filtered elements in an array already, `Where` won't be executed every time, it will be executed once you call the `ToArray` and that's it. This is the difference between the codes, based on this you can do the math for the other parts.

Comment: The problem isn't that it does the work twice; that would make the code twice as slow.  The problem is that it doubles the work *every time it recurses* which is 2^log(n) times as much work.  That's a *lot* more work.

Comment: @Servy: “twice every time you call `quicksort`” seems to cover that pretty accurately.

Comment: @Servy yes, that's correct. I didn't mean it doubles the work but forgot to mention combining queries on every call which u did in your answer, so I gave u thumbs up on that one

Comment: This is the clear,  correct answer, addressing the central point in a direct, explicit way. It's a pity to see how misleading and unnecessarily convoluted... other answers can be.